# Expected number of lattice points in $S$ is like $S$'s volume

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, proof-verification, reference-request, vector-lattices

Hel${}$lo everyone,

I think I remember a theorem going something like this:

> $L$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose base cell has area $a$. $S$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Take an element $x$ uniform on $L$'s base cell. Now
>   \begin{equation} 
>     E[\text{# of points in } S\cap (L+x)]=vol(S)/a.
> \end{equation}

I imagine the proof might go something like this:

> Call $\Lambda$ the base cell of $L$ centered about 0. Notice the expectation in question equals the sum of probabilities: \begin{align}\sum_{l\in L} P(l+x\in S)=\sum_{l\in L}\frac{1}{a}vol((\Lambda+l)\cap S)=vol(S)/a.\end{align}

Does anyone know if any of this is right or what this is called?

Thank${}$s!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial by rearranging the integral. Identify a measurable fundamental region for $L$ centered about $0$ as $B$ and take $S$ to be a bounded, measurable set.

Now it is almost immediate that
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}_{U\sim \mathrm{Uniform}(B)} \left[\ |(U+L)\cap S|\ \right] = \frac{\mathrm{vol}\ S}{\mathrm{vol}\ B}.
\end{equation}

Indeed,

> \begin{align}
>     \mathbb{E}_{U\sim \mathrm{Uniform}(B)} \left[\ |(U+L)\cap S|\ \right] &= \frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}\ B}\int_B |(U+L)\cap S| du \\
> &= \frac{1}{\mathrm{vol} B}\sum_{\ell \in L} \int_B\mathbf{1}_{S}(u+\ell) du \\
> &= \frac{1}{\mathrm{vol} B}\sum_{\ell \in L} \mathrm{vol}(B+\ell)\cap S \\
> &= \frac{\mathrm{vol} S}{\mathrm{vol} B}
> \end{align}
> where the last equality follows since $(B+\ell)_\ell$ is a tiling of space.

What I was probably thinking of was the nontrivial [Minkowski-Hlawka-Siegel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Hlawka_theorem). From Zamir's book on lattices, for each dimension n>1 there is a random ensemble of lattices with unit determinant so that for any bounded measurable set S, the expected number of nonzero lattice points in S equals the volume of S.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the same argument (obviously) succeeds for $\mathbb R^n$ replaced by any unimodular topological group, and "lattice" replaced by discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ so that $G/\Gamma$ has finite volume. But, at the same time, this kind of "soft" result, being as "generic" as it is, does not capture subtleties of situations... although, yes, at a more primitive point, it does give proofs of intuitively-plausible-but-hard-to-rigorously-prove results. :)